# Override unique_together error message in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use unique_together for two fields (email and type) for Meta for a model, but the the error message is always "The fields email, type must make a unique set." What is the best way to override the unique_together error message?

Answer (score 11):

## Option 1: At serialization

You can use `UniqueTogetherValidator` on your serializer (see http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquetogethervalidator).

Then, you can override the displayed message at initialization:

```
UniqueTogetherValidator(message='Your custom message', fields=(field1, field2,))
```

## Option 2: Model validation

Unfortunately, the error message from Django for a unique_together `ValidationError` is hardcoded. If you want to change the error message, a way I can think of is to override the `unique_error_message` method of your model.

```
def unique_error_message(self, model_class, unique_check):
    error = super().unique_error_message(model_class, unique_check)
    # Intercept the unique_together error
    if len(unique_check) != 1:
        error.message = 'Your custom message'
    return error
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it at model level instead of serializer?

Comment: Which version of Django do you use?

Comment: 1.11.4 (1, 11, 4, u'final', 0)

Comment: But I am not sure why my unique_error_message function never gets called.

Comment: I define it inside model that extends AbstractUser class AppUser(AbstractUser)

Comment: Unfortunately, serializer validation and model validation are two different things. The latter is not called by DRF as far as I know. You may have to force a call to your model instance validate_unique method if you want it to work. But I don't see the point, the easier way is clearly to use the validator from DRF.